# SVN total Line of Code Change during a selected time period or between 2 offline versions of java/jsp files

Tags: git, svn, codebase

I need to get the total line of code changed for selected files in SVN from a given day.

For example say there is a file called something.java and I need to get the COUNT of line of code change when we compare it with the version which was on 1st of Jan 2014.

I have to do it against a huge code-base and I need the stat (LOC count) of selected 50 files only.

I heart about StatSVN , but I would like to find is there any better solutions/tools which better fits my requirement.

I also can use if there a solution which give total line of code changes between 2 selected offline version of a file. 
(So that I can try to have 2 versions of codebase locally[initial and latest] without svn and get total number of line of code change of selected files within in those 2 codebases)

Comment: LOC is a meaningless metric. Don't enable people who attempt to use it for managerial/decision-making purposes.

Comment: I agree, but just to wanted to generate certain report on top of this...